# VirtualBox cannot access nginx in network

Tags: virtualbox

Hey everyone I have problem connecting with nginx in network using browser, but I can access through ssh, my network configuration of virtual box is set to bridge, with localip 192.168.1.4 in ifconfig, I used Centos7 64bit, Virtualbox 5.0.8 and my host OS Windows 7. I can ping this ip anywhere in my network. I already edit the php-fpm/www.conf, and also my default.conf, I set the listen to port 80 and server_name as 192.168.1.4 I also start and enable the nginx.service and php-fpm.service. However when I used browser to access the host http://192.168.1.4 or http://192.168.1.4:80 or 8080 i have no access, not even 404 or 502 error. How to solve this? any tutorial or links? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Centos7 by default block the web browser from accessing NGINX instance. You can curl or ping but not able to access it via port 80. I was able to do this by installing iptables and allow the traffic of web server the http Port 80 and https port 443.